# Drawing a BufferedImage to another BufferedImage is changing RGBA values

Tags: java, awt, bufferedimage, graphics2d

I have an issue trying to make a copy of `BufferedImage` object.

I'm using `drawImage (BufferedImage image, int x, int y, ImageObserver observer)` method to draw the original image on the new one, and i'm setting `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB` for each image, however, when i print the values of new image colors, the RGBA values are slightly different.

I need to make a copy of the original image because i have a `JPanel` holding an image to be drawn as background. In other parts of my application i have to get the image from the panel, but i would like to return a copy to avoid the image to be modified from elsewhere.

How can i solve this issue?

Code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
public class BufferedImageColorBug
{
    public static void main (String [] a) {
        Color [] colors = {
            new Color (202,230,186,14),
            new Color (254,65,188,214),
            new Color (247,104,197,198),
            new Color (158,93,79,239),
            new Color (235,45,57,194),
            new Color (155,77,126,150),
            new Color (164,237,20,172),
            new Color (184,106,97,191),
            new Color (187,249,135,85),
            new Color (236,112,98,24)
        };
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage (colors.length, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        for (int x = 0; x < colors.length; x ++) image.setRGB (x, 0, colors [x].getRGB ());
        BufferedImage copy = new BufferedImage (image.getWidth (), image.getHeight (), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2d = copy.createGraphics ();
        g2d.drawImage (image, 0, 0, null);
        g2d.dispose ();
        for (int x = 0; x < colors.length; x ++) {
            Color color = new Color (copy.getRGB (x, 0), true);
            System.out.println (color.getRed () + "," + color.getGreen () + "," + color.getBlue () + "," + color.getAlpha ());
        }
    }
}
```

This is the ouput i get:

```
200,237,182,14
254,66,188,214
247,104,197,198
158,93,79,239
235,45,57,194
155,76,126,150
165,237,19,172
184,105,97,191
186,249,135,85
234,117,96,24
```

**EDIT**

I talked about cloning image because this is my aim, but with this question i would like to understand *why* rgba values are different between images.

I already tried to use `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB_PRE`, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create an exact copy of your image (given they are both of the same type), you can change the code just a little bit:

```
BufferedImage copy = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
copy.setData(image.getRaster()); // getRaster() is faster than getData(), as no copy is created

for (int x = 0; x < colors.length; x++) {
    Color color = new Color(copy.getRGB(x, 0), true);
    System.out.println(color.getRed() + "," + color.getGreen() + "," + color.getBlue() + "," + color.getAlpha());
}
```

This will print the same colors as in your original `colors` array.

---

PS: I initially thought this was a bug, but realize now it likely isn't.

After some testing, I found that there's a small difference between your code and the code I normally use to clone images. If you change the alpha compositing rule to `Src` (meaning only the source will contribute and completely replace the pixels at the destination), you will also get the expected result:

```
BufferedImage copy = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

Graphics2D g2d = copy.createGraphics();
g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src); // Completely replace, default is SrcOver
g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
g2d.dispose();

for (int x = 0; x < colors.length; x++) {
    Color color = new Color(copy.getRGB(x, 0), true);
    System.out.println(color.getRed() + "," + color.getGreen() + "," + color.getBlue() + "," + color.getAlpha());
}
```

The reason is that in composing semi-transparent pixels over completely transparent pixels, the original transparent pixels at the destination will contribute to the end result, thus altering the RGBA values.